# Hel with a Activity design

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm going crazy with a activity design
I think thah the problem is with the Weights atributes but I'm not sure. The fields of the row on middle contains letters hidding and the button size expands to height (not respond to changes in width and height atributes)
The span atributes is correctly assigned?

This is a snapshot of the activity

[image]

This is a summary of the estructure

LinearLayout 1
   LinearLayout 1.1
      TableLayout
         TableRow
   LinearLayout 1.2
       TableLayout
         TableRow con imagen centrada    (span=4)
         TableRow con 4 Textviews
         TableRow con un textview que se modifica(span =2)    y un boton de continuar (span=2)
   LinearLayout 1.3
      TextView

Wich effect have really the weight attribute in nested layouts?

This is the code of activity

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

                <TableRow android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/info"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/info_pm2"
                        android:src="@drawable/infomdpi2" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/info_pm1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/pm3_3"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundcorners"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:paddingRight="25dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp" >



                <TableRow
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/instrtutpm1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_span="4"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/t3_3" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/BtnOption0"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                        android:text="A"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/BtnOption1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                        android:text="B"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/BtnOption2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                        android:text="C"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/BtnOption3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                        android:text="D"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right" >
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/respuesta"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_span="3"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/BtnNextQ"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_span="4"
                        android:text="@string/next" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|right" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/large_appname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/large_appname"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Post your image properly and format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `android:layout_span="4"` from Button Widget

Answer (score 0):

In your code I observed the button has `android:layout_span="4"` If you remove this attribute for the button and for textview and make the `TableRow`  to

```
<TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/respuesta"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/BtnNextQ"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="next" />
        </TableRow>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you and @Dynamo, your help works fine but have a question, if the previous row have 4 cells the row that contains the text and the button, each object should be spanned in 2 cells no?

Comment: If allot the weight to the row affects to cells? Is correct? In the first row that contains Imageview also remove the span?

Comment: When I select an option, the text of TextView respuesta changes to show the answer selected and the sizes of the textview of the row changes also.Where could be the problem?

thanks again

Comment: keep every width as matchparent. and assign weights to each textview to 0.25

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/info"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:contentDescription="info_pm2"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/info_pm1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="pm3_3"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="25dp">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/instrtutpm1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="4"
                    android:contentDescription="logo"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" r>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/BtnOption0"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="A"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/BtnOption1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="B"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/BtnOption2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="C"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/BtnOption3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="D"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/respuesta"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/BtnNextQ"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="next" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center|right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/large_appname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="large_appname"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you explained what is different from the code from the OP? This to help the OP but also other readers with the same problem.